# Adding Multiple Widgets to QTableWidget Cell in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a situation where i want to add 3 buttons in a QTableWidget.
I could able to add a single button using below code.

```
self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()

saveButtonItem = QtGui.QPushButton('Save')
self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0,4,saveButtonItem)
```

[image]

But i want to know how to add multiple (lets say 3) buttons. I Mean Along with Save Button i want to add other 2 buttons like Edit, Delete in the same column (Actions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply create your own widget, containing the three buttons, e.g. via subclassing `QWidget`:

```
class EditButtonsWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditButtonsWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        # add your buttons
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        # adjust spacings to your needs
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        # add your buttons
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Save'))
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Edit'))
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Delete'))

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

And then, set this widget as the cellwidget:

```
self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0,4, EditButtonsWidget())
```

Answer (score 5):

You use a layout widget to add your widgets to, then add the layout widget to the cell.

There are a couple of different ones you can use.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html

```
self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()

layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

saveButtonItem = QtGui.QPushButton('Save')
editButtonItem = QtGui.QPushButton('Edit')
layout.addWidget(saveButtonItem)
layout.addWidget(editButtonItem)

cellWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
cellWidget.setLayout(layout)

self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 4, cellWidget)
```

Comment: I think you meant `self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0,4,layout)`.

Comment: iam getting TypeError: QTableWidget.setCellWidget(int, int, QWidget): argument 3 has unexpected type 'QHBoxLayout'

Comment: OK, I had a read through the docs. Seems I was mistaken. I will update the answer. You need to add the layout to a QWidget first

Comment: @Leon Thx for the reply. it worked, but i need to set layout contentMargins and spacing to set the buttons perfectly. else the buttons are squezed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    row = 0
    self.ui.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(len(self.stopsStations))
    self.ui.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(2)
    for d, x in zip(self.stopsStations, range(len(self.stopsStations))):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.ui.btnEdit = QPushButton("")
        self.ui.btnEdit.setIcon(QIcon("./icon/edit.ico"))
        self.ui.btnEdit.setObjectName("btnEdit")
        self.ui.btnDelete = QPushButton("")
        self.ui.btnDelete.setObjectName("btnDelete")
        self.ui.btnDelete.setIcon(QIcon("./icon/trash.ico"))
        layout.addWidget(self.ui.btnEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.ui.btnDelete)
        self.ui.tableWidget_2.setItem(
            row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(d))
        cellWidget = QWidget()
        cellWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.ui.tableWidget_2.setCellWidget(x, 1, cellWidget)
        # self.ui.tableWidget_2.setCellWidget(x, 2, self.ui.btnDelete)
        self.ui.btnEdit.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)

        row = row+1
```