# Handle Event outside of init class pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5

Using the code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148968/how-to-add-multiple-qpushbuttons-to-a-qtableview) and [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764395/adding-multiple-widgets-to-qtablewidget-cell-in-pyqt/29764914#29764914), I made a GUI presenting my project on a smaller scale.

I have a qTableView,containing a large array of rows, and on each rows I have a delete and an edit button. On click, it should either edit or delete the current row. When using only the [first source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148968/how-to-add-multiple-qpushbuttons-to-a-qtableview), it works exactly as intended, but as soon as I handle the click outside of the buttons class, it stops working.

Everytime I try to edit or delete, the button that either self.sender() or QtWidgets.qApp.focusWidget() sees as the sender has the coordinates [0,0], even if it's absolutely not it's coordinates.

I have searched on various websites and can't find this precise question.
What am I doing wrong, and what could I do to solve this problem?

My code :

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox

class EditButtonsWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # Credit to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29764914/13812144

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditButtonsWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        # add your buttons
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        # adjust spacings to your needs
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        
        self.editButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('edit')
        self.deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('del')
        
        self.buttonRow = 0
        # add your buttons
        layout.addWidget(self.editButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.deleteButton)

        self.setLayout(layout)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        data1 = ['row1','row2','row3','row4']
        data2 = ['1','2.0','3.00000001','3.9999999']

        self.table.setRowCount(4)

        for index in range(4):
            item1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data1[index])
            self.table.setItem(index,0,item1)
            item2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data2[index])
            self.table.setItem(index,1,item2)
            self.btn_sell = EditButtonsWidget()
            self.btn_sell.editButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
            self.table.setCellWidget(index,2,self.btn_sell)

    def handleButtonClicked(self):
        #button = QtWidgets.qApp.focusWidget()
        button = self.sender()
        index = self.table.indexAt(button.pos())
        if index.isValid():
            print(index.row(), index.column())
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The position must be of the widget that is set in the QTableWidget, not of one of its children.

In this case it is better to consider the EditButtonsWidget as a black box and expose the clicked signals of the buttons as new signals so that the sender is EditButtonsWidget and no longer the buttons:

```py
class EditButtonsWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    edit_clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    delete_clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditButtonsWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        # add your buttons
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        # adjust spacings to your needs
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        
        self.editButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('edit')
        self.deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('del')
        
        # add your buttons
        layout.addWidget(self.editButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.deleteButton)

        self.editButton.clicked.connect(self.edit_clicked)
        self.deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.delete_clicked)
```

```py
for index in range(4):
    item1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data1[index])
    self.table.setItem(index,0,item1)
    item2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data2[index])
    self.table.setItem(index,1,item2)
    self.btn_sell = EditButtonsWidget()
    self.btn_sell.edit_clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked) # <---
    self.table.setCellWidget(index,2,self.btn_sell)
```

Comment: Hey, I apologize I lost my credentials, just found them. This answered saved me, thanks a lot, your very quick response saved me a lot of time and it really helped !

Answer (score 0):

Widget positions always use the parent's coordinate system as a reference.

In your case, the button is a child of `EditButtonsWidget`, and since it's also the first widget and the layout has no margins, the button is placed at `0, 0` in that coordinate reference system.

A theoretical solution to your problem would be to *map* the widget position to the actual widget you need a reference for, which is the *viewport* of the scroll area (the table):

```
    def handleButtonClicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        viewportPosition = button.mapTo(self.table.viewport(), QtCore.QPoint())
        index = self.table.indexAt(viewportPosition)
        if index.isValid():
            print(index.row(), index.column())
```

<sup>The mapping is done using an empty QPoint, since the top-left corner of a widget is always `0, 0` in local coordinates.</sup>

While this works, it's not the most logic nor elegant or safest way to do so, as you should reference the actual index instaed.

A better solution would be to map the table index, use that as argument of the widget constructor, and send that index for a custom signal.

```
class EditButtonsWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    editClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self, index):
        super(EditButtonsWidget,self).__init__()
        self.index = index

        # ...

        self.editButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.editClicked.emit(index))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        for index in range(4):
            # ...
            persistenIndex = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(
                self.table.indexFromItem(item2))
            self.btn_sell = EditButtonsWidget(persistenIndex)
            self.btn_sell.editClicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
            self.table.setCellWidget(index,2,self.btn_sell)

    def handleButtonClicked(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            print(index.row(), index.column())
```

Note that I used a [QPersistentModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html), which ensures that the model index coordinates are always consistent even if the model changes (by deleting/inserting items or moving them).
Also note that you cannot directly use a QPersistentModelIndex for most functions that take a normal QModelIndex as parameter; in case you need that, you can recreate a QModelIndex like this:

```
    modelIndex = self.table.model().index(
        persistentIndex.row(), persistentIndex.column())
```